# Implement custom Microsoft sync

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

How can I sync tables with some filter using the sync framework?

eg:
I want to sync only records with `UserId=n` for a particular user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filtering is supported out of the box, you should check the documentation:

[Walkthrough: Defining Filtered Scope and Provisioning Server Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928601.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Provisioning a Client Database with Filtered Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928642.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Executing Synchronization for the Filtered Scope [SQL Express]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928759.aspx)

if your using the Local Database Cache Wizard or the older sync provider:

[How to: Filter Rows and Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726003)